# C# Regular expression abba

Tags: c#, regex

It could be Numbers and letters, like this

```
ABBA
abba
1221
2332
```

The left and right sides are the same and the middle two are the same

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you tried anything yet? If so, please show what you've tried and what the results were. I suspect this will help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/backreference-constructs-in-regular-expressions

Comment: `(.)\1{1,}` The full match, `Group[1]` retains the symbol that is repeated (two or more times).

Comment: You may want to read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `(.)(.)\2\1`.
Where `\1` references the first capturing group, and `\2` references second.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this one can match 4 identical ones like aaaa aaaa 1111 2222, how can it not match them

Comment: @missliu I cannot reproduce your problem, I matched `abba`, `-00-` and `0..0` correctly.

Comment: var re = @"(.)(.)\2\1";  var b = new Regex(re).IsMatch("AAAA"); Console.WriteLine(b); You try this one, it will pass

Comment: @missliu of course it will pass, `aaaa` is a special pattern of `abba`, if u want to only match `abba`, try `(.)(.)\2(?!\2)\1`.

Comment: (.)(?!\1).(?!\1).\1  This will be all right, but yours will be all right, thank you